# firefox - html5 video - default video fallback does not show

Tags: html, firefox, video

I use latest firefox browser and I want to show the default `fallback message` when video format does not supported by firefox (as html5 documentation described), but firefox only show `poster` image and text on it "*No video with supported format and MIME type found*"

Any ideas how to show `This is FALLBACK MESSAGE content` (as it must showed) instead of `firefox error message`? thanks

```
<video poster="movie.jpg" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
        <p>This is FALLBACK MESSAGE content</p>
</video>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per spec, the browser must not show the fallback if it supports `<video>`, even if it happens to not support the provided codecs.....  Hence the behavior you're seeing in Firefox: the spec requires that behavior.

Comment: its a pity that I can not show flashplayer when codes does not supported. :(